# Hide Add New Item Icon in Async refresh also

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-server

I am having a **LVWP** on a custom **WebPart** page.
Got few properties set for webpart are as follows:

- Inline editing is allowed
- ASync refresh is allowed
- Manual Refresh is allowed

Now the problem I am facing is, in this **LVWP** an icon is displayed for adding new item. I need to hide/remove that icon, since I don't want my users to add any items from there.

I have added javascript to remove it, which is working fine, The icon is not displayed on page load.

The challenge here is this LVWP has ASync refresh on, which refreshes the WebPart, and the icon gets displayed. `$(document).ready(function () {}` this method never gets called because of ASync refresh. How can I hide this icon in all scenarios.

**Icon Snapshot:**

[image: This is the icon]

Comment: I guess, if you select No Toolbar in Toolbar type it will not show that icon. This option is available in webpart properties when you edit webpart.

Comment: Toolbar = No Toolbar already set,

Comment: <Property Name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</Property>        Toolbar is not a property in LVWP. Actual property is ChromeType in sharepoint.

Comment: @DipenShah ChromeType & ToolBar, both properties are available in SharePoint LVWP.

Comment: @Gaurravs  As per microsoft , Toolbar is not getting on MSDN.https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart_properties.aspx . can you send me the link where toolbar is used. i want it for my code. i am using sharepoint 2013

Comment: I am using SP 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was pretty simple, instead of using js, css made my work

```
.s4-itm-hdrcol{
    display:none;
}
```

Incase of ***ASync*** refresh also, this css property get retained